# No such destination

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe method in my website. user purchase product from my site and payment done through stripe.
I want to charge my commission and send rest of money to Service Provider.
When i try to use transfer method in stripe it shows me Error Message.

```
"message": "No such destination: acct_1###############",
```

Even my account added with providers account.

I am using the code below for this

```
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
     "amount" => 50,
     "currency" => "eur",
     "destination" => "acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi",
     "transfer_group" => "ORDER_95"
));
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: "No such destination" means that the account id you've provided doesn't exist or isn't connected to your platform, or perhaps you are using a secret key belonging to a different account. 

If you believe that's in error I'd talk to Stripe's support. https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: Hi @duck. I m trying to connected to that account id with main account but unable to attach accounts.
Please tell me how can i connect 2 accounts

Comment: What kind of account is `acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi`? A regular stripe account, or one of their Express/Custom accounts? Stripe describes the connection flow here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was using different Stripe api test keys across the app (I'd copied a test key from somewhere else on SO).

So when I went to create a payment, stripe couldn't find that connected user on the platform account.

To correct this, I simply ensured the Stripe test key was consistent throughout (I'll make it an env variable when it ships to production)

```
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51HYHSFGtUKse83O9J4QeAib3cp8sHzGKHAL8JdkshEzuYQKUCKEP3CHE3AIUb7fdevMK7TVAUCyJU0ADSwIUoX00qxZmBI9r'
```