# Strip "Transfer" & "Payout" Issue "No such destination" PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments, strip

When i try to send money to another stripe account it shows the error

`Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_THWS8JfPOYcSrv) No such destination: "accountid" thrown in stripe-php\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php on line 38`

For Transfer I used

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('SITE_KEY');
$transfer= \Stripe\Transfer::create([
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'transfer_data' => [
    'destination' => 'other_stripe_account',
    ],
]);
```

For Payout I used

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('SITE_KEY');
$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create([
'amount' => 50,
'currency' => 'usd',
'destination' => "other_stripe_account",
],
["stripe_account" => "MY_STRIPE_ACCOUNT"]);
```

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016969/no-such-destination

Comment: You can use your own wallet system and for transaction you can use paypal and all other process you can use database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the any other account to send money with strip you can only use those accounts which are you creating in your dashboard like "Connect Accounts" than you can transfer money to those accounts.